# Angular two different paths same menu item active

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, menuitem

I have a menu like this in my `app-component.ts`:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" routerLink="/shop" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">Shop</a>
  </li>

</ul>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

with a route file like this one

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'shop',
    component: ChildComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'details',
    component: DetailComponent
  }
];
```

As you can see, I have "shop" and "details" components. Details components can be reached from the shop page by clicking a simple button. In this moment my active state on the menu selects the shop item correctly, but when I click the details button the state is no more active. Is it possibile keep the active state in the menu for both components even if I am in another route?

Here's an example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/parent-child-active-x6sp1e

Comment: Is `details` independent of `shop`? It kind of looks like it should be a child route

Comment: Well, could be a child route. But it should not appears on the menu (details I mean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#nesting-routes), your appRoutes should be like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ 
 path: 'shop',
 component: ChildComponent, 
  children: [
    {
      path: 'details', 
      component: DetailComponent
    }
   ] 
 }
```

But, to reach success here, you need to have two `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. One inside your Home and another inside your Shop.

Comment: There are 2 problems in this way. Unfortunally seems that the menu doesn't keep the active state. The second one is that now in the shop component I have also the detail component when I click the button "Go to details". Both, instead  of only details. I don't know if you get me

Comment: Ok, for best practices with Angular, I think your 'detail' route should be a child route of 'Shop'. You can solve the second problem with a simple *ngIf trick, when you click the button the <h2> desapear. About the first problem, I'm trying to fix it.

Comment: Solved: remove the [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" from your shop <a>

Comment: Yeah it's working now. Problems solved! Thank you very much.

Comment: FYI i saw this information here https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive#description